# sorting a list inside of a data.table vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table of strings which I am trying to turn into lists and sort without sorting the vectors themselves:

```
> DT <- data.table(x=c("A11, A12, A41",
+                      "A11, A41, B11, A6, A21",
+                      "A41, A12",
+                      "A12, A41",
+                      "A12, A6, B41, A93"));DT
                        x
1:          A11, A12, A41
2: A11, A41, B11, A6, A21
3:               A41, A12
4:               A12, A41
5:      A12, A6, B41, A93
```

which I need to get to:

```
                        x
1:          A11, A12, A41
2: A11, A21, A41, A6, B11
3:               A12, A41
4:               A12, A41
5:      A12, A6, A93, B41
```

I've tried a using a bunch of `order`ing, `as.lists`, and in `data.frames`, as well as a `data.table` function I tried to write:

```
sortlists <- function(DT,col){
  for(i in 1:length(DT[,col])){
    DT[i,col]=order(DT[i,col])
  }
}
```

which throws an error that my column position is greater than ncol(x). Regardless, there must be a better way to get the result I want. I'm fairly new to R and am very new to data.tables (which I would like to impliment more since I have heard good things) so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: note that `order` and `sort` put "A12" ahead of "A6"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I just did that by hand - I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will split the character vectors then sort and return a list for each row

```
 DT[, list(y =  lapply(strsplit(x,', '), sort))]
                    y
1:        A11,A12,A41
2: A11,A21,A41,A6,B11
3:            A12,A41
4:            A12,A41
5:     A12,A6,A93,B41
```

And. if you really wanted the single character strings for each row

```
DT[, list(y =  vapply(strsplit(x,', '), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ', '), FUN.VALUE =character(1)))]
```

Comment: For the second one, I think it should be `sapply` or `vapply` to get a character vector instead of a list.